# How to add different number of port dynamically to node according to its type in gojs flow chart

Tags: gojs

I'm new to go js and having hard time to figure out how to limit the number of port in a particular node.
the number of incoming and out going port should be different for diferent node for e.g. **start** node should have  0 incoming node and 1 outgoing port and end node should have  2 incoming node and 0 outgoing port. My code to define template as follows:

```
 myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Spot",
    { locationSpot: go.Spot.Center, toolTip: tooltiptemplate },
    new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
    { selectable: true, selectionAdornmentTemplate: nodeSelectionAdornmentTemplate },
    { resizable: true, resizeObjectName: "PANEL", resizeAdornmentTemplate: nodeResizeAdornmentTemplate },
    { rotatable: true, rotateAdornmentTemplate: nodeRotateAdornmentTemplate },
    new go.Binding("angle").makeTwoWay(),
    // the main object is a Panel that surrounds a TextBlock with a Shape
    $(go.Panel, "Auto",
      { name: "PANEL" },
      new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size", go.Size.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Size.stringify),
      $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",  // default figure
        {
          portId: "", 
          fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer",
          fill: "white",  
          strokeWidth: 2,
            toMaxLinks:1, //this is where i can limit the number but cant determine the type of node
            fromMaxLinks:2

        },
      new go.Binding("figure", "figure"),
      new go.Binding("fill", "fill"),
      new go.Binding("stroke", "stroke")),
      $(go.TextBlock,
        {
          font: "bold 8pt Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif",
          textAlign: "center",
          margin: 8,
          maxSize: new go.Size(160, NaN),
          wrap: go.TextBlock.WrapFit,
          editable: true
        },
        new go.Binding("choices"),
        new go.Binding("id"),
        new go.Binding("State"),            
        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
    ),
    // four small named ports, one on each side:
    makePort("T", go.Spot.Top, false, true),
    makePort("L", go.Spot.Left, true, true),
    makePort("R", go.Spot.Right, true, true),
    makePort("B", go.Spot.Bottom, true, false),
    { // handle mouse enter/leave events to show/hide the ports
      // mouseEnter: function(e, node) { showSmallPorts(node, true); },
      // mouseLeave: function(e, node) { showSmallPorts(node, false); }
    }
  );
```

as mentioned  in comment i know where i can  limit the number of port but i cannot determine which node is being worked upon at that time.

can someone please help .
please leave comment if you need more clearification .

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions, depending on what flexibility you want to have.

The easier way to go is to have a separate template for each kind of node.  This is demonstrated by the Logic Circuit sample: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/logicCircuit.html.

[image: Logic Circuit sample]

Note that because defining templates is just JavaScript code, you can define functions and use constants or variables to make the definition for each template much clearer and easier to maintain.  This allows for relatively simple node data objects in the model, because there is no need for describing anything about ports in the data.

The opposite extreme is to define a single template that can be parameterized in all possible manners that you might need.  Because there can be such a wide range of appearances and behaviors, there isn't a good comprehensive example of that.  But the Dynamic Ports sample, https://gojs.net/latest/samples/dynamicPorts.html, demonstrates have a completely variable number of ports on each side of a rectangular body.  Ports can be added and removed dynamically by the user -- there are context menus both for nodes and for ports.

In this case each node data object in the model has to have complete port descriptors for each port on each side of the node. And the template is much more complicated.

[image: Dynamic Ports sample]

Naturally you can combine the two approaches, by having separate node templates for certain special cases (such as inputs or outputs) and one or a few slightly general node templates for other kinds of nodes.